AC-JTAG Capacitor Value for differential signal testing
How to compute the value of AC-coupling capacitor to be used in AC-JTAG for testing high-speed differential signal?
Can anyone give a more detailed insights on the proper consideration when implementing the AC-JTAG.
The AC-coupled net forms a high pass filter, and with this I'm using the cutoff frequency formula to get the capacitor value.

Given the following, i get a value of almot 160pF.
(for the cutoff frequency, i adjusted it lower than the operating frequency 12.5MHz, so that the amplitude of the output will be almost the same as the input)
fc = 10 MHz
R = 10 ohms
By the way, i have read some notes on IEEE 1149.1 and 1149.6, and found this one.

It says that in AC coupled line with 0.01uF, the frequency of the test pattern can be less than 5Mhz. Using the value of capacitor, cutoff frequency seems to be in the 160KHz range. Is it really needed to set the cutoff frequency this low, even though its AC-JTAG testing?
I also found another post regarding the capacitor in PCIe, which explains the usage of the 200nF capacitor value.

In AC-JTAG implementation, should these also be considered?
I'm wondering if i can use a more lower capacitor value (in pF range) so that cutoff frequency will not be too far away with the operating frequency.
And one more thing, if the capacitance is too small, charge will accumulate quickly and will the output stays at High?
